# JSON-API upload image file

Tags: javascript, media

I have been struggling to set up headless Drupal with React js. I did manage to upload the image via JSON API, as per instruction [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/file-uploads)

But I am not able to display the image. It would be great if anyone could help me with what went wrong.

For the image in code, I used base64. Whereas it has mentioned Buffer Format, I could not find out how to convert images to Buffer Format.

```
await axios({
  method: "post",
  url: baseurl.URL + '/jsonapi/media/image/field_media_image/',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'X-CSRF-Token': csrftoken, 
    "Content-Disposition": 'file; filename="' + imageName + '"',
    'Authorization':'Basic cmFqan989kjjhjWFuZG8hOTg0MQ==',
  },
  data: Buffer.from(imageToBase64,'base64')
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

}

```
images?.map((item, index)=> {
    
      return <li className="card">   
            <img width="100" 
            src={item.imgurl} 
            alt={item.filename} />
            <div className="text-sm">{item.imgurl}</div>
      </li>
    })
```